# Spring MongoTemplate upsert entire object

Tags: spring, upsert, mongotemplate

For Upsert `MongoTemplate` provides one method to be used in following way.

But, it will set only the name. What if I want to insert all keys associated with the new User Object. i.e apart from name, I want to insert email and many other values.
I can use `set("key","name")` for each item, but is it possible to save the entire object for upsert.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is("Markus"));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("name", "Nick");
mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, User.class);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591032/spring-mongotemplate-update-merge was helpful
tl;dr 
`Update update = Update.fromDBObject(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$set", your_ob).get());`

Answer (score -1):

I guess `save` can do that for you. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e1654).

Answer (score -1):

`mongoTemplate.save(user); or 
mongoTemplate.save(user,"customer");//if you need to save it in another collection name.`

> save will perform
>   an insert if the object is not already present else it will update,
>   that is an 'upsert'.